# Iptables and Plusserver Firewall

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a Plusserver Firewall and need to add two rules to allow me to access an http and https website.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d 00.00.00.00 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -d 00.00.00.00 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

If i use only one line will work, any of each these but not both in same time.

**I restarted the firewall.** and nothing.

Thanks.

Later edit: I found the problem. At the end of each line should have an **;** close line.

Answer (score 0):

Thought the fault could be in the --state, can your try this example

> > iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d 00.00.00.00 -m state --state **NEW,ESTABLISHED** -j ACCEPT
> >
> > iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -d 00.00.00.00 -m state --state **NEW,ESTABLISHED** -j ACCEPT

When it doesn't success, you can take a look at this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-11-how-to-block-or-open-httpweb-service.html